# Сжать PDF с нескольких страниц до минимального количества

Tags: php, pdf

Имеется документ PDF, либо много документов PDF, на них есть небольшие картинки, но распечатывать эти картинки накладно, на каждую картинку один лист. Мне нужно сделать что бы все картинки умещались на минимальное количество листов, то есть, есть 100 листов, из них получится к примеру 3 листа заполненых.
Все это нужно либо программой из командной строки. Либо на PHP. Ничего подобного не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала, можете извлечь все изображения, используя [pdfimages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402862/extract-images-from-pdf-with-php), а затем сгенерировать HTML страницу с <img> тэгами, и конвертировать в PDF.

Comment: пдф то хоть полноценный, а не скан?

Comment: Pdf когда как. Когда полноценный. А когда скан. По поводу pdfimage попробую. Спасибо